# Spring Design Patterns recomendation for a rest application

Tags: spring, rest, design-patterns

First time developing a REST application, and no previous knowledge on Spring Framework. Almost all Web applications I have developed are in PHP (Laravel), C# (ASP.NET and MVC) or Python (Django).

When the subject is design patterns, I get really confused.

Using the guides available on https://spring.io/guides (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/), I see that a design pattern was to use:

**Entity**, **Repository**, **Service** and **Controller** (RestController), like:

When user request a `/user/{id}` (just a example), the **Controller** ask for the **Service** to return the user, so, the **Service** ask to **Repository**, that return with a **Entity**, and so, the **Service** pass this **Entity** to **Controller** (at least in this example);

```
request = Controller -> Service -> Repository -> Entity
response = Repository return Entity -> Service -> Controller
```

First thing:

is this correct? I known this works, but it's a common practice (or at least a "best practices")?

For me, don't appear to be correct pass a `Entity` (if this entity is a exact representation of a object in the database) to my `controller`.

Suppose that my Entity has a password property. I'm passing the password to my `controller`. Sure I can "hide" the password on `service` before return to the `controller`, but still, the `controller` will be receiving a `entity` with a password property.

Now, on reverse way. Suppose that I want to create a new user (`Entity`), and in my database, I have a property with `expirationDate` which is calculated automatically, based on the registration date. My `Entity` representation must have a `expirationDate` property, but in post, I don't need (and I should not) pass any value to this property.

What's the "best practices" in this cases? In C# / MVC / ASP.NET, normally I used a new Entity for theses cases (aka `ViewModel`).

Looking at http://www.robertomarchetto.com/java_rest_api_best_practices_spring_boot, I see another design pattern, and appear that exist a `Entity` (or `DTO`) for every type of response (like `UserResponseDto` and `UserRegistrationDto` in my example - **DAO is the same than Repository?**).

So, in my example is correct to use this pattern?

```
request -> Controller -> Service -> Repository -> Entity (DB representation)
response -> Repository return a Entity -> Service convert Entity to a DTO -> Controller
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the service

- **return type**: introduce a [`transfer object`](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) that holds only the data that the **controller needs**.
- **parameter type**: introduce a [`transfer object`](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) that holds only the data that the **service needs**.

I summerized my thoughts about service layer designs in my blogs that you might be interested in:

- [Pros and cons of service layer designs](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2012/01/12/pros-and-cons-of-service-layer-designs/)
- [Separation of api and implementation](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2012/02/26/separation-of-api-and-implementation/)
- [Simplify service layer design using bean validation – jsr-303](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2012/02/05/simplify-service-layer-design-using-bean-validation-jsr-303/)

Comment: Thanks! The [Simplify service layer design using bean validation](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2012/02/05/simplify-service-layer-design-using-bean-validation-jsr-303/) is something new for me! Really helpful! :D